# Webdriver, CSharp, C# - Cannot switch between windows

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck when trying to switch windows using the latest version of webdriver in C#.

I have a base window, when i click a button, it opens a new window.

The target code for this button is as below.

```
window.open(uri, "DisplayPage", " width=1200, scrollbars=yes , resizable = yes ,   toolbar =  no , menubar =  no");
```

I am using the below mentioned code to target the new window

```
   string BaseWindow = _driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

   ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = _driver.WindowHandles;

    foreach (string handle in handles)
    {

        if (handle != BaseWindow)
        {
            _driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Title.Equals("DisplayPage");

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from above, I am switching to the window using the Target Title from the base window. This does not seem to work.

I then noticed that the Title of the opened window was different, it was "Display - Transaction Page"

I then modified  the code to this

```
 string BaseWindow = _driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

       ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = _driver.WindowHandles;

        foreach (string handle in handles)
        {

            if (handle != BaseWindow)
            {
                _driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Title.Equals("Display - Transaction Page");

            }
        }
    }
```

Still no luck.

Interestingly, I do not get any errors saying "Window not found".

The problem is that When i try to click on elements on the newly opened page, i get a NoSuchElementException which means that the newly opened window has not been targeted.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Hasan

Comment: Doh! Who would've thought. The newly opened window was not part of "Trusted Sites" in IE.

My Code was correct, after adding the target URL to my trusted sites, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You should break the loop once window changed to your window, otherwise it will always switch to last opened window:

```
foreach (string handle in handles) {
 if (handle != BaseWindow) {
  if(_driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Title.Equals("Display - Transaction Page")) 
    break;
  }
}
```

You can try with `Contains` instead of `equal`, it will simplify the window search:

```
_driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Title.Contains("Display");
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you cracked the answer yourself, there is another way to handle switching between the windows in C#.

```
// initiate webdriver
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//perform some action to open a new window. Like clicking a link.
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnId")).Click();

//switch to new window.
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

//if you want to switch back to your first window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
```